# Buffer Memory in a Client-Server Model

Tags: java, client-server, buffer

I am writing a basic client-server program where I send a file from the client to the server. I using a BufferedReader to upload the file from the client to the server, but I had a question about where it would exactly be stored on the server.

From my understanding, buffer memory is only temporary and doesn't necessarily save information. So how would I ensure that a file would be saved on the server? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader doesn't store the whole stream in memory, just parts of the stream so you are aren't reading a byte at a time from I/O.

You'll need to read in the entire stream with BufferedReader, and store it in memory, assuming you have enough space, using something like StringBuilder, or store it on the server file system by using a FileWriter.